# Проблема с формированием запроса

Tags: sql-server

Я начал изучать базы данных и столкнулся с проблемой, а именно не могу сформировать запрос по следующим условиям, которые указаны в задаче:

> "По каждому автору просчитать процент публикаций относительно всех
> публикаций по конкретному журналу"

Ниже пример моей базы данных на картинке, а так же, код создания базы данных. Вы не могли бы мне помочь в решении моей проблемы?
Работаю в СУБД SQL SERVER.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
CREATE table Журналы( 
   id_журнала INT identity  PRIMARY KEY ,
   Название VarChar(100) NOT NULL,
   Издатель VArChar(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE table Выпуски_журналов( 
   Индентификатор_выпуска INT identity PRIMARY KEY,
   id_журнала INT references Журналы,
   Номер_выпуска INT NOT NULL ,
   Год INT 
); 
CREATE table Публикации( 
   Код_публикации INT identity PRIMARY KEY,
   Индентификатор_выпуска int references Выпуски_журналов,
   Название_публикации VArChar(100) NOT NULL ,
   Страницы INT check (Страницы>=1 and Страницы<=15) 
); 
CREATE table Авторы(
   id_автора INT identity PRIMARY KEY,
   ФИО VArChar(100) NOT NULL ,
   Дата_рождения  DATE,
   Пол VArChar(100) 
); 
CREATE table АвторПубликаций( 
  Код_публикации  int references Публикации,
  id_автора int references Авторы
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Принципиально так:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT [автор], 
         COUNT(*) [count] 
  FROM [публикации] 
  GROUP BY [автор]
)
SELECT [автор], 
       100 * [count] / SUM([count]) OVER () [percent] 
FROM cte;
```

Правильные связывание таблиц и выделение "конкретного журнала" - за свой счёт.